# putting conditional user access on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

So, I have an ajax script and there's a user that can see the table yet it can't update nor delete the data on the table. here's the script

```
function tampil_data_asum(){
        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : 'json_asum',
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].tertanggung+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].no_polis+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].tgl_polis+'</td>'+
                            '<td>Rp.'+number_format(data[i].premi)+'</td>'+
                            '<td>Rp.'+number_format(data[i].komisi)+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].keterangan+'</td>'+
                            '<td class="text-center">'+
                                '<button  class="btn btn-success btn-xs asum_detail" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>'+' '+
                                 '<button  class="btn btn-info btn-xs asum_edit" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'+' '+
                                '<button " class="btn btn-danger btn-xs asum_hapus" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#show_data_asum').html(html);
            }

        });
    }
```

I want to put conditional on the button  so when the user logs in, he can't access these buttons

Comment: if the button is there, in the HTML, there is not much you can do to prevent the user accessing that button. All security must be serverside to be effective

Comment: you can send logged in and logout value in ajax response from controller . And on that value you can apply conditions.

Comment: do not use async : false.  then who is that he? generally you can write function instead of doing within the success function

Comment: @Aroon the user I mentioned

Comment: do u have number of user's name to whom the buttons are non-clickable?

Comment: @Aroon let's say that the user with level = 5 can't click the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your condition based on user's levels, I would suggest this `css` method. Just check the user level in if condition

```
    var html = '';
    var i;

if(user_level >= 5) { 
//add one css class which will make the button non-clickable 

    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            html += '<tr>'+
                              //your other tds
                             //added the no-click class to the buttons
                                    '<td class="text-center">'+
                                        '<button  class="no-click btn btn-success btn-xs asum_detail" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>'+' '+
                                         '<button  class="no-click btn btn-info btn-xs asum_edit" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'+' '+
                                        '<button " class="no-click btn btn-danger btn-xs asum_hapus" data="'+data[i].id_asum+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>';
                        }

} else {
//no need add the class to the buttons. just paste your existing code


}

                    $('#show_data_asum').html(html);
```

css:

```
.no-click {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Does it helped?